# Lost internet connectivity: IP address using CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, ip-address

I changed the IP address of my linux machine so that I can communicate with a device.  I modified the IP address in the ifconfig-eth0 file to the necessary IP address (IPADDR=192.XXX.X.XXX).  I can successfully communicate with my device, but when I rewire my computer to the internet, I cannot connect.

I tried to change the IP address in ifconfig-eth0 back to what google told me my IP address is  (130.XXX.XX.XXX), and ran

```
    service network restart
```

But I am still unable to connect.  Any ideas?

Comment: Run `ifconig`, `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and `route -n` to look for more clues.

Comment: I saw nothing unusual in these files, however I solved the problem using the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by configuring /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 (as root) to contain only the following:

```
    DEVICE="eth0"
    BOOTPROTO="dchp"
    ONBOOT="yes"
```

Upon restarting the machine, a new IP address was obtained and I was able to connect to the internet.